# How to read values from multiple regions of AWS using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I need to get list from multiple regions of AWS Account. From a single region I am able to fetch the list. The issue is getting that list from multiple region. I need to know how to use a `for` loop in connecting line.

I use boto3 with Python 3.

```
   region = ['us-east-2','us-east-1']
   conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
   instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
    for instance in instances:
        instance_count.append(instance)
        instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
    print('Instance count ->' + str(len(instance_count)))
```

I need to know how to use a `for` loop to check the array inside a region variable?

I expected to print all resources from two regions.
I am getting error as:

> if region_name in service_data['endpoints']: 
>        TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do.

```
regions = ['us-east-2','us-east-1']

for region in regions:  
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)

    instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])
    for instance in instances:
        instance_count.append(instance)
        instanceCount = str(len(instance_count))
    print('Instance count ->' + str(len(instance_count)))
```

---

In order to print the number of instances,

```
regions = ['us-east-2','us-east-1']
num = 0

for region in regions:  
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,region_name=region)
    instances = conn.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'stopped']}])

    for instance in instances: num += 1

print('Instance count -> {}'.format(num))
```

Comment: I am trying to get the count of the instances from multiple AWS Regions. I tried this already but i am getting printed count of 1 region first and second region then. I want to combine them.

Comment: is that mean you don't need to print others?